# Prove that $\sqrt{x} + x$ approaches $2$ as $x$ approaches $1$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

How to prove using the epsilon-delta definition of a limit that $\sqrt{x} + x$ approaches $2$ as $x$ approaches $1$?
What is the value of delta?

I'm having a difficulty of this one because of the equation $f(x) = \sqrt{x} + x$. Any help will do!

Comment: Welcome to this Stack Exchange! Please read through https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question for assistance in asking your first question. Generally speaking, homework problems will not be (and *should not* be) answered on here unless you provide a description of what you've tried, where you're confused, et cetera. This is not a problem solving website, and while we do help with problems, you should really come here for suggestions by asking pointed questions about what *exactly* you are having a difficult time with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have: $|\sqrt{x}+x - 2|= |\sqrt{x}-1+x-1|\le |\sqrt{x}-1|+|x-1|= \dfrac{|x-1|}{\sqrt{x}+1}+|x-1|\le 2|x-1|$. Thus for every $\epsilon > 0$, choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{2}$, then if $0 < |x-1| < \delta \implies |\sqrt{x}+x-2| < 2\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon. $